# Replace String inside json inside Array Javascript

Tags: json, array, replaceall, replace

Hello guys I have a js file that has a list of json that have the next structure:

```
[{"label":"9312 - Item1",     "value":"9312"},
 {"label":"9313 - Item2",             "value":"9313"}]
```

And I want to get rid of the "" in key the json attributes to have something like this:

```
[{label:"9312 - Item1",     value:"9312"},
 {label:"9313 - Item2",             value:"9313"}]
```

Could someone tell me how to achieve this? Or put an example?
Thanks

Comment: This sounds like an X-Y problem (i.e. you're describing the solution you want instead of focusing on the overall problem you're trying to solve). Doing this would make the string not be JSON any more. If you're dead set on this though, a few of the tags you included (specifically, "replaceall") would be a good place to start. What have you researched on that so far? What have you tried?

Comment: Well you could just parse the JSON and you will get the structure without ""

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar Question in [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3651294/remove-quotes-from-keys-in-a-json-string-using-jquery/3651373#3651373). Here is the extract.

```
let str = `[ { "id": "n1", "label": "Node 1", "score": 1.0 },{ "id": "n2", "label": "Node 2", "score": 2.2 },{ "id": "n3", "label": "Node 3", "score": 3.5 } ]`;

str = str.replace(/"(\w+)"\s*:/g, '$1:');

console.log(str);
```

Output

```
[ { id: "n1", label: "Node 1", score: 1.0 },{ id: "n2", label: "Node 2", score: 2.2 },{ id: "n3", label: "Node 3", score: 3.5 } ]
```